# Where are virtual switches kept in vSphere? (through pyVmomi)

Tags: python, vmware, vsphere

I have a number of virtual portgroups on a virtual switch. When I execute

```
datacenters = si.RetrieveContent().rootFolder.childEntity
for datacenter in datacenters:
    hosts = datacenter.hostFolder.childEntity
    for host in hosts:
        networks = host.network
        for network in networks:
             print network.name
```

(si is a service instance)
I get all the vlans (portgroups) on the network, but none of the switches (which the docs claim should be in the network directory). Given that folders also have the name attribute, any folders that I looked over should have been printed. So where does vsphere/vcenter keep these switches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve **vSwitches** with **pyVmomi** you can do:

```
def _get_vim_objects(content, vim_type):
    '''Get vim objects of a given type.'''
    return [item for item in content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(
        content.rootFolder, [vim_type], recursive=True
    ).view]

content = si.RetrieveContent()
for host in self._get_vim_objects(content, vim.HostSystem):
    for vswitch in host.config.network.vswitch:
        print(vswitch.name)
```

Result would be:

```
vSwitch0
vSwitch1
vSwitch2
```

---

To retrieve **Distributed vSwitches** you can use the **_get_vim_objects** function (above) with vim_type=**vim.dvs.VmwareDistributedVirtualSwitch** parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this still helps @Magitrek but a sysadmin friend of mine without an account pointed out that this is the correct answer, as opposed to the 2014 answer, hence the up-vote + down-vote to re-order these. "The first answer is completely wrong, it refers to port groups. The second answer is completely right, it refers to actual vSwitches."

Answer (score 0):

Getting host.network will give you an array of network objects, but not the switch info. To get switch info this is probably the most straightforward approach

```
datacenters = si.RetrieveContent().rootFolder.childEntity
for datacenter in datacenters:
    networks = datacenter.networkFolder.childEntity
    for network in networks:
        print network.name
```

The network folder has the virtual switches as well as all the portgroups.

Comment: This does the same thing as the code in my question, i.e. prints the portgroups, but not the switches. I'm certain that there are switches, as when I run `esxcli network vswitch standard list`, I find three switches. My question is how to get instances of them.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have anywhere to test that has standard vswitches, but the code I posted does list out Distributed Virtual Switches. I would have thought that standard vswitches would also be listed, but maybe not.

Comment: I found a test vCenter that has a standard switch and I do see the standard switch when I run that code. Can you post a screen shot of what you see in the network tab of the vCenter web client and what you get from the script?

Comment: In the network tab, it doesn't show any switches. It shows the vmcenter, with the host under it, and all the vlans under that. Both your tool and an esxcli portgroup query show all the vlans. If I run the esxcli portgroup query though, it shows that each vlan is associated with a virtual switch.

Comment: If it's not showing up in vCenter than the pyVmomi module won't see it. It sounds like something is configured on the individual esxi host that isn't showing up in vCenter, I'm not sure why that would be the case.

Comment: Yeah, things are getting rather strange. I tried creating a new virtual switch, and added a new portgroup to it through esxcli. It's the exact same thing as the old ones: the vlan shows up in networks, but the switch only shows up when I query switches through esxcli.

Comment: Also, it seems that I can make distributed virtual switches, which show up in all the right places, but none of my host machines support them. Still hoping for a solution using standard virtual switches.

Comment: Just a general bit of advice, migrate to do distributed virtual switches if you can. It's so much easier to manage in the long run.

Comment: I figured out my overarching problem, but still have no idea where the switches are kept. Assigning a virtual machine to a standard portgroup only requires a reference to the portgroup, and not the switch.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to find all DV switches in vCenter and check versions.

```
def find_all_dvs():
Q = "DVS unsupported versions"
try:
    log.info("Testing %s" % Q)
    host_ip, usr, pwd = vx.vc_ip, vx.vc_mu, vx.vc_mp  # Reusing credentials
    is_Old = False
    si = connect.SmartConnect(host=host_ip, user=usr, pwd=pwd, port=int("443"))
    datacenters = si.RetrieveContent().rootFolder.childEntity
    for datacenter in datacenters:
        networks = datacenter.networkFolder.childEntity
        for vds in networks:
            if (isinstance(vds, vim.DistributedVirtualSwitch)): # Find only DV switches
                log.debug("DVS version: %s, DVS name: %s" %(vds.summary.productInfo.version, vds.summary.name))
                if loose(vds.summary.productInfo.version) <= loose("6.0.0"):
                    is_Old = True
    if is_Old:
        log.info("vSphere 7.x unsupported DVS found.")
        return
    else:
        return

except Exception as err:
    log.error("%s error: %s" % (Q, str(err)))
    log.error("Error detail:%s", traceback.format_exc())
    return
```